# Which database pool middleware approach is more efficient?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, middleware, connection-pooling

I'd like to know how these approaches work, as reading the documentation just confuses me exactly what happens.

## 1. Pool module, required where needed

Does a pool get created each time we require the pool? If the pool module is required in 3 places, will 3 separate pools exist?

**pool.js**

```
const pool = mysql.createPool(db);

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);

module.exports = pool;
```

**api.js**

```
const pool = require("../pool");

await pool.query(query);
```

## 2. Route middleware, with a passed in request property

This way there is only one pool (I think), and only that one is used. Does it work as I think it does?

**app.js**

```
const middleware = require("./middleware.js");

let app = express();

let pool = mysql.createPool(db);

app.all("/api/*", middleware(pool));
```

**middleware.js**

```
module.exports = (pool) => {

    return (req, res, next) => {

        pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {

            const asyncQuery = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

            req.asyncQuery = asyncQuery; // <--------- pass pool up the chain
            req.connection = conn;

            next();
        });
    };
};
```

**api.js**

```
router.get("/api/route", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
 
        await req.asyncQuery(query); // <-------- use the passed in pool

        res.status(200).send(rows);

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Release the connection in middleware, instead of releasing it in the route handler.

Await next and release it in finally block just like the router handler.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please post how the code would look like, as I don't quite understand. Also, does this mean that the second approach is better?